# access objects and change its value at the same time

Tags: python, numpy, class, object

I was wondering if there is a way to access an object values, do some calculations and save it to the same place at the same time?

Assume you have this:

```
import numpy as np
class Marker(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name: str
        self.location: np.ndarray
        self.quality: np.ndarray

data = Marker()
data.name = "sample"
data.location = np.array[1,2,3]
data.quality = 0.1
```

How can I do a calculation on on data.location for example multiply it by 2 and save it back where it is?

I have a list of objects and I am trying to filter them one-by-one and save it back where it was:

```
for l in data:
    l.location = signal.filtfilt(*ba, l.location, axis= 0)
```

Comment: Many numpy operations modify the array in place, call one of them instead of a function that returns a new array.

Comment: Can you explain it with an example?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html lists all the numpy array functions. The ones that don't say that they return an array modify the given array.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to filter my location data with `signal.filtfilt` function in `scipy`. Can I do the same thing with this function?

Comment: its [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html) says: **Returns
yndarray
The filtered output with the same shape as x.** So it returns a new array, it doesn't modify the array in place.

Comment: So you need to write `data.location = signal.filtfilt(data.location, ...)`

Answer (score 1):

Just do thE calculation and assign back to the attribute.

```
data.location = some_function(data.location)
```

Comment: I have a list of that object that I am accessing them in a loop. Does it work it this case also?